# Can I track my ticket that my company may have booked?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings, emirates

Is it possible to track a potential Emirates ticket that my company may have booked (from Karachi to Dubai) when I have no information with reference to booking information (and company is keeping it a secret from me). Though I have all my personal information (obviously).

So is there a way to see if a ticket has been booked against my name/passport etc?

Comment: do you have a frequent flier account with the airline, and did you give that number to the company also? If so, you may see it under "upcoming flights" - some programs do this and some don't. TBH if a company is buying me plane tickets and actively keeping the information from me, I have a problem that will not be solved by establishing when the tickets are for, so I am not sure why you feel the need to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Online this is surely impossible because there's just no way to prove you are you and so the airline won't divulge this information. Say, a spouse is trying to get out of a hairy situation and the other party in the marriage calls the airline. Said person would have all the personal information, passport number, DOB, name, whatnot and yet the passenger would be most unhappy and potentially in danger if a secret getaway were revealed. Or it could be an unscrupulous police officer, who again will have all the data. The possibilities are endless. This will not and can not happen.

Comment: Your faith in the resistance of airline call centres to social engineering is touching. That said, without a PNR, FF# or even date, it will be difficult for the airline to help even if they wanted to.